# CSS overlapping when I shorten the browser window

Tags: css

I have still having some CSS trouble with this and I cannot seem to fix it.
I just made a **[test page](http://phpblog.inutritie.ro/test.html)** here to see if anyone can help:

The html:

```
<div class="menu_background">
    <div class="menu">This is my menu</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #FFC;
margin:0;
padding:0
}
.menu_background {
background:url(images/headline.jpg) repeat-x;
}
.menu {
width:60em;
margin:0 2em;
border:solid 1px #F00;
color:#FFF
}
```

The problem: there is a weird overlapping happening when you shorten the browser window, making it smaller than 60em.

You can look at the test page and here are two screenshots:

**1. This is when the browser is full size:**
[image]

2. This is when i **shorten the browser window and scroll right:**
   [image: **enter image description here**]

The best way is to look at my [test page](http://phpblog.inutritie.ro/test.html) and see for yourself.

Comment: Latest Mozilla, IE 9. What browser do you use? did you notice the behavior on the test page?

Comment: This is really weird, it shouldn't and It gives me great problems with my layout which

Comment: It is not a problem depending on the browser in use. Yet, I can't figure out how it can be fixed right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid that put the background in your menu directly

```
.menu {
  background:url(images/headline.jpg) repeat-x;
  width:60em;
  margin:0 2em;
  border:solid 1px #F00;
  color:#FFF
}
```

(review)
to have background 100%

```
.menu_background {
   background:url(http://phpblog.inutritie.ro/images/headline.jpg) repeat-x;
   min-width: 64em;
}
```

Comment: You are right, but I want the background to go full window size, and center the menu which will have another backgrpund

Answer (score 2):

`.menu_background
{
min-width:56em
}`

Comment: Ty, thought of that myself, but it still leaves a margin to the right, and If I increase the min width, horizontal scroll appears. I'll edit the post with an example. http://phpblog.inutritie.ro/test2.html

Comment: `.menu {
max-width: 56em;
width: auto;
}`
 and delete `min-width: 57em;`

Comment: I think it worked Ozerich, I just increased the min-width to 57em, and horizontal scrolling didn't appear. Is this a proper solution? cross browser? What is causing the behavior?

Comment: Or `.menu_background { min-width:56.1em }` if you want to keep scrolling and fill that small line at the edge.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in Chrome, Mozilla and IE (latest versions). It seems it's only happening in IE.

How about:

```
.menu_background {
    position:relative;
}
```

and

```
.menu {
    position:absolute;
}
```